# C# XNA Matrices - Calculate moon rotation around axis with matrices

Tags: c#, math, matrix, xna, matrix-multiplication

I am building a 3D simulation.

I am using one class to display sun, planets & moon with different size, texture, speed and orbit. Here's my code which does the magic job of calculating rotation + revolution

```
world = Matrix.CreateScale(size,size,size) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(0,0,0) * 
 Matrix.CreateRotationY(rotation) * 
 Matrix.CreateTranslation(position) * 
 Matrix.CreateRotationY(revolution);
```

- **size** is my variable to scale the object individually
- **rotation** is my variable to rotate the object around its own axis
- **position** is my variable to position the planet on orbit, new Vector3(240,0,0)
- **revolution** is my variable to revolve the planet around the origin

now i want the display the moons around earth and around other planets but i just can't figure out how to do it. In terms of Matrix Multiplication.

The complication is the moon's revolution is around a planet which is not on origin and is always changing.

**How to do it ?**

Comment: It's highly unclear what your matrices are doing, but I suggest you apply the revolution of the moon around its planet, then the revolution of the planet around the sun.

Comment: this is my technique of revolution round origin, i need a technique for revolution around another body, i am unable to figure it out.

Comment: Not sure, but try multiplying by the planet's position matrix instead of the origin. What that should do is shift your calculation so instead of calculating where the moon is in world space, you're doing it in the planet's space and then translating it to world space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured it out...

**Translate The Origin to the Parent planet's Current Location**

and keep doing it in the update method

```
world = Matrix.CreateScale(size,size,size)
        * Matrix.CreateTranslation(0,0,0) 
        * Matrix.CreateRotationY(rotation)
        * Matrix.CreateTranslation(position)
        * Matrix.CreateRotationY(revolution); 

world *= Matrix.CreateTranslation( parent.getPosition() );
```

what i am doing here is that i m revolving the moon around the origin (Sun) but i translate its origin to any planet's current location... this worked for me.

Comment: Cool, I was (basically) right. Just so you know, what's going on here is when you do your first calculation, you're operating in world space, where (0, 0, 0) is the center of the world. But, when you multiply by the position matrix of the planet, you are translating your moon's position in world space into the planet's space, where the planet's position is the origin (0, 0, 0). Make sense?

Answer (score 2):

In your `Draw` method, after you've drawn the planet/moon that you want to orbit around:

```
Matrix satellite = Matrix.Identity
                 * Matrix.CreateScale(orbitScale)
                 * Matrix.CreateRotationY(orbitSpin)
                 * Matrix.CreateTranslation(0f, orbitDistance, 0f)
                 * Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle(orbitAxis, orbitRotation);
effect.View = satellite * camera.View;
```

So, in your `Update` method, you can then do:

```
orbitRotation += MathHelper.PiOver2 * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
orbitRotation = MathHelper.WrapAngle(orbitRotation);
orbitSpin += MathHelper.TwoPi * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
orbitSpin = MathHelper.WrapAngle(orbitSpin);
```

I've defined `orbitAxis` as a `Vector3`.  `orbitDistance`, `orbitRotation`, `orbitScale` and `orbitSpin` as `float`'s.

Comment: http://cid-641cd5a494d0369d.office.live.com/self.aspx/.Documents/WindowsGame2.rar - is a working example using that code.